# Toggle jQuery | отобразить-свернуть блоки из списка поочередно, а не все сразу

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет. Задача вроде бы простая, но видимо не для меня пока. Есть перечень блоков с услугами, которые идут друг за другом. 
Внутри типичного блока с одной конкретной услугой есть следующие блоки:

- Наименование услуги;
- Описание и подготовка;
- Цена;

Также есть скрытый блок (display: one) с классом `service__items__item__specification`, который должен отображаться при клике на блок Описание и подготовка (`.services__items__item__description`).
Хочется реализовать отображение этого блока снизу(типа `slideDown()`) при клике на блок Описание и подготовка. Метод `.slideToggle()` отображает все блоки одновременно. А нужно, чтобы блоки отображались поочередно + одновременно сворачивался предыдущий открытый блок. Пробовал реализовать нашедшие на просторах интернета решения - с методами `removeClass()` и `addClass()`, но по непонятным для меня причинам, они не работают для моей ситуации.

```css
.services__items {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 30px;
  gap: 15px;
}

.services__inner {
  border-top: 1px solid #ADB5BD;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ADB5BD;
  height: auto;
}

.services__items__item {
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 15px 0px 15px 0px;
}

.services__items__item__name {
  flex-basis: 872px;
}

.services__items__item__name__categories {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: -5px;
}

.services__items__item__name__categories__icon {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.services__items__item__name__categories__category p {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #ADB5BD;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.services__items__item__name__categories__icon {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.services__items__item__description,
.services__items__item__price {
  text-align: right;
  text-align: 22px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.services__items__item__price {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.services__items__item__price__icon {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.service__items__item__specification {
  display: none;
  justify-content: left;
  gap: 36px;
  margin-top: 115px;
  padding: 0px 0px 30px 0px;
}

.service__items__item__specification p {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #ADB5BD;
}
```

```html
<div class="services__items">
  <div class="services__inner">
    <div class="services__items__item">
      <div class="services__items__item__name">
        <h5>Наименование услуги</h5>
        <div class="services__items__item__name__categories">
          <div class="services__items__item__name__categories__icon">
            <img src="img/Line.svg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="services__items__item__name__categories__category">
            <p>Категория услуги</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="services__items__item__description container-md">
        <a href="#">описание <span class="decoration-text-md">и</span> подготовка </a>
      </div>
      <div class="services__items__item__price container-sm">
        <div class="services__items__item__price__digits">
          <p>1400</p>
        </div>
        <div class="services__items__item__price__icon">
          <img src="img/CurrencyRub.svg" alt="" height="22" width="22">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="service__items__item__specification">
      <div class="container-md service__items__item__specification__definition">
        <h6>описание</h6>
        <p>Текст описания.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="container-md service__items__item__specification__preparation">
        <h6>подготовка</h6>
        <p>Текст подготовки.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="services__inner">
    <div class="services__items__item">
      <div class="services__items__item__name">
        <h5>Наименование услуги</h5>
        <div class="services__items__item__name__categories">
          <div class="services__items__item__name__categories__icon">
            <img src="img/Line.svg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="services__items__item__name__categories__category">
            <p>Категория услуги</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="services__items__item__description container-md">
        <a href="#">описание <span class="decoration-text-md">и</span> подготовка </a>
      </div>
      <div class="service__items__item__specification">
        <div class="container-md service__items__item__specification__definition">
          <h6>описание</h6>
          <p>Текст описания.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="container-md service__items__item__specification__preparation">
          <h6>подготовка</h6>
          <p>Текст подготовки.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="services__items__item__price container-sm">
        <div class="services__items__item__price__digits">
          <p>1400</p>
        </div>
        <div class="services__items__item__price__icon">
          <img src="img/CurrencyRub.svg" alt="" height="22" width="22">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="services__inner">
    <div class="services__items__item">
      <div class="services__items__item__name">
        <h5>Наименование услуги</h5>
        <div class="services__items__item__name__categories">
          <div class="services__items__item__name__categories__icon">
            <img src="img/Line.svg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="services__items__item__name__categories__category">
            <p>Категория услуги</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="services__items__item__description container-md">
        <a href="#">описание <span class="decoration-text-md">и</span> подготовка </a>
      </div>
      <div class="service__items__item__specification">
        <div class="container-md service__items__item__specification__definition">
          <h6>описание</h6>
          <p>Текст описания.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="container-md service__items__item__specification__preparation">
          <h6>подготовка</h6>
          <p>Текст подготовки.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="services__items__item__price container-sm">
        <div class="services__items__item__price__digits">
          <p>1400</p>
        </div>
        <div class="services__items__item__price__icon">
          <img src="img/CurrencyRub.svg" alt="" height="22" width="22">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Селекторы, которые использовал для реализации toggle:

- при клике на `.services__items__item__description` должен отображаться блок `.service__items__item__specification`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Хочется реализовать отображение этого блока снизу(типа slideDown()) при клике на блок Описание и подготовка. Метод .slideToggle() отображает все блоки одновременно. А нужно, чтобы блоки отображались поочередно + одновременно сворачивался предыдущий открытый блок.

Предложу такой вариант с `jQuery`...

```js
$('.services__items__item__description').on('click', function(){
  const o = $(this).parents('.services__inner').find('.service__items__item__specification')
  const od = o.get(0)
  const oc = $('.services__items .service__items__item__specification.on').filter((i, e) => e != od)
  if (oc.length) {
    oc.removeClass('on').slideUp('slow', _ => {
      toggle()
    })
    return
  }
  toggle()
  //
  function toggle() {
    if (o.hasClass('on')) {
      o.slideUp()
      o.removeClass('on')
      return
    }
    o.slideDown()
    o.addClass('on')
  }
})
```

```css
.services__items {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 30px;
  gap: 15px;
}

.services__inner {
  border-top: 1px solid #ADB5BD;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ADB5BD;
  height: auto;
}

.services__items__item {
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 15px 0px 15px 0px;
}

.services__items__item__name {
  flex-basis: 872px;
}

.services__items__item__name__categories {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: -5px;
}

.services__items__item__name__categories__icon {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.services__items__item__name__categories__category p {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #ADB5BD;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.services__items__item__name__categories__icon {
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.services__items__item__description,
.services__items__item__price {
  text-align: right;
  text-align: 22px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.services__items__item__price {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.services__items__item__price__icon {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.service__items__item__specification {
  display: none;
  justify-content: left;
  gap: 36px;
  margin-top: 115px;
  padding: 0px 0px 30px 0px;
}

.service__items__item__specification p {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #ADB5BD;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="services__items">
  <div class="services__inner">
    <div class="services__items__item">
      <div class="services__items__item__name">
        <h5>Наименование услуги</h5>
        <div class="services__items__item__name__categories">
          <div class="services__items__item__name__categories__icon">
            <img src="img/Line.svg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="services__items__item__name__categories__category">
            <p>Категория услуги</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="services__items__item__description container-md">
        <a href="#">описание <span class="decoration-text-md">и</span> подготовка </a>
      </div>
      <div class="services__items__item__price container-sm">
        <div class="services__items__item__price__digits">
          <p>1400</p>
        </div>
        <div class="services__items__item__price__icon">
          <img src="img/CurrencyRub.svg" alt="" height="22" width="22">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="service__items__item__specification">
      <div class="container-md service__items__item__specification__definition">
        <h6>описание</h6>
        <p>Текст описания.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="container-md service__items__item__specification__preparation">
        <h6>подготовка</h6>
        <p>Текст подготовки.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="services__inner">
    <div class="services__items__item">
      <div class="services__items__item__name">
        <h5>Наименование услуги</h5>
        <div class="services__items__item__name__categories">
          <div class="services__items__item__name__categories__icon">
            <img src="img/Line.svg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="services__items__item__name__categories__category">
            <p>Категория услуги</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="services__items__item__description container-md">
        <a href="#">описание <span class="decoration-text-md">и</span> подготовка </a>
      </div>
      <div class="service__items__item__specification">
        <div class="container-md service__items__item__specification__definition">
          <h6>описание</h6>
          <p>Текст описания.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="container-md service__items__item__specification__preparation">
          <h6>подготовка</h6>
          <p>Текст подготовки.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="services__items__item__price container-sm">
        <div class="services__items__item__price__digits">
          <p>1400</p>
        </div>
        <div class="services__items__item__price__icon">
          <img src="img/CurrencyRub.svg" alt="" height="22" width="22">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="services__inner">
    <div class="services__items__item">
      <div class="services__items__item__name">
        <h5>Наименование услуги</h5>
        <div class="services__items__item__name__categories">
          <div class="services__items__item__name__categories__icon">
            <img src="img/Line.svg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="services__items__item__name__categories__category">
            <p>Категория услуги</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="services__items__item__description container-md">
        <a href="#">описание <span class="decoration-text-md">и</span> подготовка </a>
      </div>
      <div class="service__items__item__specification">
        <div class="container-md service__items__item__specification__definition">
          <h6>описание</h6>
          <p>Текст описания.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="container-md service__items__item__specification__preparation">
          <h6>подготовка</h6>
          <p>Текст подготовки.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="services__items__item__price container-sm">
        <div class="services__items__item__price__digits">
          <p>1400</p>
        </div>
        <div class="services__items__item__price__icon">
          <img src="img/CurrencyRub.svg" alt="" height="22" width="22">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо, работает. но при каждом клике на ссылку (Описание и Услуги), я возвращаюсь на вверх страницы.

Comment: решил вопрос удалением href="" из ссылок. Спасибо!!!